# How does duration_cast round

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

If I convert to a coarser unit of time (say `std::chrono::minutes` to `std::chrono::hours`) how will `duration_cast` round? For example, what value will `std::chrono::minutes(91)` become if converted to `std::chrono::hours`? 2h, 1h?

Comment: It shouldn't take much time to write a quick test program, and figure out the answer.

Comment: The algorithm is described in  [time.duration.cast] (e.g. [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cplusplus/draft/master/papers/n4582.pdf)).

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468068/whats-the-difference-between-floor-and-duration-cast

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`duration_cast` always rounds towards zero.  I.e. positive values round down and negative values round up.

For other rounding options see:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html

`floor`, `ceil`, and `round` are currently in the draft C++ 1z (hopefully C++17) draft working paper.  In the meantime feel free to use the code at [chrono_util.html](http://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_util.html), and please let me know if you have any problems with it.

---

## C++ 17 update

- [std::chrono::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/floor)
- [std::chrono::ceil](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/ceil)
- [std::chrono::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/round)

---

```
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1400ms)  ==  1s
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1500ms)  ==  1s
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1600ms)  ==  1s
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1400ms) == -2s
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1500ms) == -2s
std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1600ms) == -2s
```