# What's the Difference Between floor and duration_cast?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono, floor, c++17

So in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) the Chrono Library provides, [`duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast):

> Computations are done in the widest type available and converted, as if by static_cast, to the result type only when finished

And [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s [`floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/floor):

> Returns the greatest duration t representable in ToDuration that is less or equal to d

So for all `x` will the result of these 2 calls be equal:

1. `chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(x)`
2. `chrono::floor<chrono::seconds>(x)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I can tell, same as the difference between `static_cast` and `std::floor`: Negatives are rounded down instead of truncated toward zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    std::cout << "duration_cast:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.4s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(1400ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.5s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(1500ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.6s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(1600ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.4s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(-1400ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.5s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(-1500ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.6s: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(-1600ms).count() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "floor:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.4s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1400ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.5s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1500ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1.6s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(1600ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.4s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1400ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.5s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1500ms).count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-1.6s: " << std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::seconds>(-1600ms).count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
duration_cast:
1.4s: 1
1.5s: 1
1.6s: 1
-1.4s: -1
-1.5s: -1
-1.6s: -1
floor:
1.4s: 1
1.5s: 1
1.6s: 1
-1.4s: -2
-1.5s: -2
-1.6s: -2
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/SsmpRz6RkvbL6Sru

Comment: Correct.  And this becomes very necessary when dealing with a `system_clock::time_point` that represents a point in time prior to 1970, and you want to truncate it to a count of days prior to 1970:  `auto d = floor<days>(tp);`.  `time_point_cast` would round up towards the next day, whereas `floor` rounds down to the start of the day which `tp` refers to.  Similar issues with `durations`, but the killer app for `floor` is making calendrical computations work for pre-1970 dates.

Comment: Ah, we've been graced by a visit from the time lord himself, @HowardHinnant just to put a plug in for his wisdom, check this out: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date