# When I compile chrono time of c++11, It report error

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

The code most like

```
  uint64_t nanoseconds = 0;
  auto nano = std::chrono::nanoseconds(nanoseconds_);
  system_clock::time_point tp(nano);
```

It report error(QNX):

```
time.cpp:86:35: error: no matching function for call to 'std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock>::time_point(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long int, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >&) 
qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:769:5: note: candidate: 
template<class _Duration2> std::__1::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration>::time_point(const std::__1::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration2>&,
typename std::__1::enable_if<std::__1::is_convertible<_Duration2, 
_Duration>::value>::type*) time_point(const time_point<clock, _Duration2>& t,
^ qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include/c++/v1/chrono:769:5: note: template argument 
deduction/substitution failed: time.cpp:86:35: note: 
'std::__1::chrono::duration<long long int, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >'
 is not derived from 'const 
 std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, _Duration2>''
```

How can I combine `std::chrono::nanoseconds` with  `time_point`

Thanks for all.

Comment: By adding them. e.g. `std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);`

Comment: First of all please try to create a [mcve] to show us (and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)). With slight modifications your code should build, [as it did in this test](https://ideone.com/Mn2rU3). And please tell us what compiler you're using, what version of it, and what flags you provide when you're compiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::chrono::time_point` [does not have a constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point) that takes an *arbitrary* duration type as a template parameter. The constructor that takes `system_clock::time_point::duration` constructs a time point with its `time_since_epoch()` property set to the specified argument, i.e., the constructed time point represents the time which is the specified duration after its "epoch."

If this is your intent, you can use [`duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) to cast your nanoseconds value to `system_clock::time_point::duration`:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

nanoseconds nano(1234567);

system_clock::time_point time(
    duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(nano));
```

Or, you can construct a `system_clock::time_point` with a duration of zero (i.e., a time point representing the epoch) and then add your nanoseconds value to this; the result is a new time point:

```
system_clock::time_point epoch;
system_clock::time_point time = epoch + nano;
```

As alluded to by Howard Hinnant, the standard does not guarantee any particular precision for `std::chrono::system_clock::duration`, i.e., the system clock may not be capable of measuring intervals as small as a nanosecond. On my system (Linux x86_64, gcc 7.3 / glibc 2.20) the duration precision is 1 nanosecond, but on other platforms it may be 1 microsecond or less. On such a platform, the result of `duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(nanoseconds(1))` is zero, since [`duration_cast` rounds toward zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122428/how-does-duration-cast-round).

(Note also that even if the precision is 1 nanosecond, the *accuracy* probably isn't! This is another topic though.)

Comment: Upvoted.  Extra info: On @darbe's platform `system_clock::duration` is very likely `microseconds`.